# Power Series in Two Variables and Radius of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

Let $\alpha > 0$, $\beta > 0$, and assume that the power series with real coefficients
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n,m = 0}^{\infty} a_{n,m} x^{n} y^{m}
\end{equation}
is absolutely convergent for every real $x, y$ such that $|x| < \alpha$, $|y| < \beta$. Then you can rearrange the terms of the series in ascending powers of $x$ as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f_n(y) x^{n},
\end{equation}
where the function $f_n:(-\beta,\beta) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are analytic functions. For every fixed $y \in (-\beta,\beta)$, let $R(y)$ be tha radius of convergence of the series in $x$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f_n(y) x^{n}.
\end{equation}
Is $R$ a continuous function of $y$?
I guess that, generally speaking, the answer is negative, but I have no counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^n\sin y)x^n.$ If $y\in \mathbb R
\setminus \pi\mathbb Z,$ then

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}|2^n\sin y|^{1/n} = 2.$$

Hence for those values of $y,$ the radius of convergence is $1/2.$ On the other hand, if $y \in \pi\mathbb Z,$ then the series vanishes identically and the radius of convergence is $\infty.$

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice and simple example!